# Add/append Latitude to Firebase array iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

I want to store the latitude and longitude of a user in Firebase but as an array.

When a button is clicked in my app, it gets the users location coordinates and stores them in my Database, but it replaces the old coordinates with the new ones (because I *set* value) but how do I *add* (or *append*) to the value?

I don't want to make an array of the coordinates in my app and then add *that* to my database, because it needs to be in real time.

Comment: There are probably other and better ways to store your data than arrays. But, for us to help you, we need to understand the question and see an example of the code you're having difficulty with. Please clarify the question, include you code and explain the expected result. Then we can take a look and try to assist. We also need to know which Firebase product you're using, so add that as a tag please.

Answer (score 0):

Let try with

```
let node = dbRef.childByAutoId()
node.setValue(value)
```

Comment: How does this store the longitude and latitude as an array?

Comment: @Jay How do you think with this structure node.
 https://i.imgur.com/qsngOFs.png
. Each `AutoId` will be a element of array `location_data`

Comment: That's a great structure but not an array (which is what the OP asked for). However, arrays should generally be avoided in NoSQL databases if possible so your proposed structure is *excellent*. Please include the structure in the question to show what your code does.